# Cuda location error while building tensorflow from source

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I'm building tensorlfow from source, but I'm facing error when it comes cuda path while I run configure. That is what it asks:

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.1 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]:

My cuda installation was from ubutnu packages.

I think cuda is installed. When I run

```
nvcc --version
```

I get output as

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

Want to know how to find out cuda toolkit location. 
I tried with /usr/lib/cuda, /usr/local/cuda, /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit, /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin. None of these are working.

I get error as "NameError: global name 'cuda_toolkit_path_full' is not defined
"

Any pointers to find out correct location location where CUDA 9.1 toolkit is installed will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you trying to compile from source?

Comment: I'm using version 1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the /usr directory after which it stopped showing that error.